# How do I ensure vertical alignment is set as middle in a table cell in IE6?

Tags: css, internet-explorer-6, html-table

I have to design a page to be compatible with IE6; it's a client requirement.

The content in my `<td>` is meant to be vertically aligned to the middle of the cell, but it's aligning to the bottom of the cell by default. However, when it's clicked on, it reverts back to middle vertical alignment.

HTML

```
<table border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tr>
    <td>Utility Payments</td>
    <td valign="top" style="border:1px solid #0C0;">
        <div class="select_box_container index01" style="border:1px solid #F00;">
            <h2>-- Select Utility Payment --</h2>
            <ul id="UtilPay" style="z-index: 10;">
                <li data-val="0" class="subhead">-- Electricity --</li>
            </ul>
    </div>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

CSS

```
.select_box_container {
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 241px;
}

.select_box_container select {
    background: url(../images/text-box.png);
    background-color: transparent;
}

.select_box_container {
    position: relative;
    overflow: visible;
}

.select_box_container h2 {
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #333333;
    margin: 0px;
    background: url(../../../pgmerc/instpy/images/text-box.png);
    padding: 6px 10px;
}

.select_box_container ul {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FFFFFF;
    border: 1px solid #F1F1F1;
    display: none;
    height: auto;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    position: absolute;
    max-height: 247px;
    top: 29px;
    width: 240px;
}

.select_box_container ul li {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #F1F1F1;
    font-size: 12px;
    list-style: none outside none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 2px 10px;
    width: 204px;
}

.select_box_container ul li:hover { background: #F7F7F7 !important; }


.index_container {
    background: url("../../../pgmerc/instpy/images/zero.png") no-repeat scroll 400px center #EAF3FA;
    border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
    padding: 9px 20px;
}

.index_container table td {
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #003976;
    padding-right: 20px;
}

.index_container h1 {
    color: #003976;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

How do I get it to only align to the middle of the cell?

Reference images for before and after are below:

[image: On Load]

[image: On Clicked]

Comment: can u post your code?

Comment: Oh. My. Goodness. IE6 in 2014 (it was released 13 years ago) - poor soul :(

Comment: there is not much in the code but i can share it please wait..

Comment: it's client requirement we have to do it ;(

Comment: If you post a public link to your images, someone with more rep will edit them in for you.

Comment: try to give some width and or height to your table to help IE6 size it before page is totally loaded.  position:relative; can be a way too  to reflow(force refresh and calculation) of the table-layout at screen.

Comment: I have posted my code for reference...

Comment: just posted the same.

Comment: So it looks like `position: absolute;` is the problem. Is that needed?

Comment: I hope you're getting paid well.

Comment: not me it's my company :)

Comment: @misterManSam you are right! there is position relative on container and absolute on inner content, but that's the necessary code for desired functionality, can you please suggest any alternative?

Answer (score 2):

Thanks all..have found solution.

I have removed the position relative from my container that is $(".select_box_container") and added it back on h2 click.... $(".select_box_container").css("position","relative");

Answer (score 0):

Just a hunch

Can you try and replace

```
<h2>-- Select Utility Payment --</h2>
```

with

```
<span>-- Select Utility Payment --</span> or div
```

Comment: there is some script linked with h2, i can't replace it at one go ;(